# R, ggplot: Decimals on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a bar plot, similar to this MWE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg=mpg/1000) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

What I get is the following (keep in mind that it is nonsense, but serves illustration purposes):
[image]
Now, I want the decimals replaced from the percentages on the y-axis ("30%" instead of "30.0%"). What can I do?

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845002/percent-labels-in-scale-x-log10), but couldn't make the function `NRPercent` does not work (and can't comment there).

Comment: See the question linked to as a possible duplicate, but also look at `?scales::percent`. The function you're using for labeling multiplies values by 100 and tacks on a percent sign, so a number like 0.0125 will come out as 1.25% by default. There's an argument for setting the accuracy to drop the decimals.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With the new version of `scales` you can use:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a post that would help out : [How do I change the number of decimal places on axis labels in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722202/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-decimal-places-on-axis-labels-in-ggplot2)

I posted the solution here just so you have it here. Added percent sign to values.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg=mpg/1000) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl, y=mpg*100)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous("Percent", labels = function(x) paste0(sprintf("%.0f", x),"%"))
```

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer to include percent sign.

Comment: This works; however, line 2 and 3 can be clarified to
    `mutate(mpg) %>%`
    `ggplot(aes(x=cyl, y=mpg/10)`

Comment: @Lukas, in that case there is no need for the `mutate` at all! Just `ggplot(mtcars, aes(........`